# auto-complete search options

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to build a search feature on my php website that provides an auto complete feature.  I've noticed that a lot of people are recommending jquery UI autocomplete.  But I took a look at their example online and it seems to take a really long time to search their example "birds" database. I haven't taken the time to analyze the sampel code to see if there's a way to speed it up.  But I just thought I'd ask to see what other ways i should be exploring to accomplish the same thing.
Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI's Autocomplete is rich and awesome. If your concerned about speed of getting items from a Database using AJAX, consider the approach of pre-populating a JSON array of the relavent information, embedded on the page. Then its pretty darn near instant (you'll just have a bunch of bloat on the page)

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

**That being said**, the speed at which AJAX can call the page, to query the database and return the data, is entirely dependant on your connection and the server its running on. jQueryUI's autocomplete is really fast, I can vouch for it

Take a look through their documentation, you'll be surprised at how flexible this library is. The remote datasource example looks like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hey!  Thanks for taking the time to respond.  i'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

While building autocomplete/realtime search features in your web site, you might as well consider using services like rockitsearch.com . It is free web service for building autocomplete/search frond ends.